# Is it possible to have horizontal stack with 2 stack items of same width?

Tags: office-ui-fabric, office-ui-fabric-react

I am trying to create a form with 2 controls inside a horizontal stack but I can't figure how to make stack use 100% of the width
[image]

Answer (score 0):

use grow={3} on each child <Stack.Item>
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/controls/web/stack